# Convert a spatial polygon object to data frame using R

Tags: shapefile, cartography, r, ogr

My goal is to modify an existing shapefile by merging certain polygons.

After importing the shapefile and using the UnionSpatialPolygons command, I get the polygon outline that I want.

However, this is now a SpatialPolygons object and not a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, so I'm unable to export it to a shapefile using writeOGR.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: If the answer below was useful, you should select it as the correct one by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer text.

Answer (score 21):

As the name says, a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame is basically just a SpatialPolygons object with data attached (the attribute table).
The data must have at least as many rows as there are features

```
library(rgdal)
ob <- SpatialPolygons(..)# Your SpatialPolygons Object
spp <-     SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(ob,data=as.data.frame("yourData"),proj4string=CRS("+proj=    aea > +ellps=GRS80 +datum=WGS84"))
writeOGR(spp,"shapes","testShape",driver="ESRI Shapefile",)
```

----EDIT----

If you want to convert your `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` back to a `SpatialPolygons` object you just need to address the object structure within R

```
ob <- SpatialPolygons(spp@polygons,proj4string=spp@proj4string)
```

Comment: For sure, @Curlew is right. Make sure to specify `IDs` argument correctly when executing `UnionSpatialPolygons`. Otherwise you might get trouble specifying `data` argument when converting back to `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

Comment: Sure, quite easy. I edited the original answer for that

Comment: I only recently started working with shapefiles and still trying to familiarise myself with this. What exact is should be substituted for youData in `data=as.data.frame("yourData")`? After dissolving inner polygons using `unionSpatialPolygons(...)`, I would like to write result as new shapefile

Comment: You need to have a data.frame with the same number of rows as you have features in your SpatialPolygons object. Better ask a new question regarding you `union` issue..

Comment: @Curlew Thank you, just posted new questions here http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/121405/40108

Answer (score 10):

Problems:

1: the outcome of UnionSpatialPolygons is a spatial polygon

2: converting the result back into a spatial polygon data frame is a real pain

-a. you need a very exact data frame to attach to a spatial polygon

-b. data you used for UnionSpatialPolygons has more rows than the output and is not formatted in the way that is needed.

My (ugly) solution:

```
### Coerce into spatial polygon data frame with id and row name of spatial polygon

# Make a data frame that meets the requirements above:

df<- data.frame(id = getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(your.spatialpolygon))
row.names(df) <- getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(your.spatialpolygon)

# Make spatial polygon data frame
spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(your.spatialpolygon, data =df)

# Then don't forget to make sure the projection is correct
# XXXX is your SRID

proj4string(spdf) <- CRS("+init=epsg:XXXX");
spdf <- spTransform(spdf , CRS("+init=epsg:XXXX"));
```

Comment: Error in if (length(Sr@polygons) != nrow(data)) stop(paste("Object length mismatch:\n    ",  : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning messages:
1: use *apply and slot directly