# Create merged polygons in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to take zip code shapefiles and merge them into larger areas.  I've looked up several links but I just can't seem to figure it out, and I keep getting stuck on the cut function in the examples that I have reviewed.  All of the examples that I have been able to find use the cut function in R but they all split arbitrarily using a percentile function.  I want to aggregate based on a grouping that isn't guaranteed to have a simple numerical range that defines the group.  I am also curious if anyone knows why the Census data is missing some zip codes?  I have pasted my code below.

Here are the links that I have already checked:

- https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/PolygonDissolveOperationsR
- [Convert a spatial polygon object to data frame using R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61633/convert-a-spatial-polygon-object-to-data-frame-using-r/61636#61636)
- [Creating new shapefile after merge operation using unionSpatialPolygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121405/creating-new-shapefile-after-merge-operation-using-unionspatialpolygons)
- https://gist.github.com/mbacou/5880859

---

```
# Objective:  Read Zipcode polygons (currently using census source, but it appears to missing some zipcodes:  Anybody know why?),
# Merge zipcodes into 'sub counties' (an internal concept, each zipcode belongs to a single sub county) and aggregate data by that 'sub county'
# Ideally this would output a TopoJSON map

# Required packages
pacman::p_load("rgdal","rgeos","maptools","gridExtra","geojsonio")

# Import US zipcode data (original source is here: http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2015/shp/cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k.zip)
us <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/Users/MyUsername/Documents/R/Data/ZipShapes", layer = "cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k")

# Create a subsetted US polygon for only AZ, simplifying for this single example
AZZips <- as.factor(85001:87000)
AZOnly <- subset(us,us@data$ZCTA5CE10 %in% AZzips)
AZOnly@data <- droplevels(AZOnly@data)
AZOnlyDF <- AZOnly@data
AZOnlyDF$ID <- row.names(AZOnly@data)

# Data frame with zip code and 'sub county' relationship
Col1 <- as.factor(
      c("85938","85932","85924","85920","85930","85940","85927","85925","86502","85936","86505","86511","86545","86028","86556","86507"
        ,"86547","86535","86508","86512","86544","86514","86504","86549","86506","86538","86515","86540","86503","86023","86020","86036"
        ,"86015","86022","86044","86017","86053","86038","86024","86035","86018","85931","86045","86435","86339","86016","86052","86040"
        ,"86001","86005","86003","86004","86002","86046","85603","85607","85636","85643","85627","85616","85638","85670","85608","85630"
        ,"85625","85671","85602","85650","85632","85620","85615","85626","85635","85606","85655","85613","85617","85610","85644","85605"
        ,"85609","85552","85543","85548","85546","85536","85541","85553","85235","85544","85532","85542","85539","85554","85501","85502"
        ,"85547","85550","85545","85292","85533","85534","85357","85371","85328","85344","85325","85359","85346","85334","85348","85379"
        ,"85387","85311","85376","85358","85372","85382","85312","85374","85308","85373","85375","85310","85378","85342","85388","85390"
        ,"85383","85361","85318","85224","85246","85286","85225","85280","85249","85284","85233","85287","85226","85283","85244","85227"
        ,"85285","85248","85236","85295","85298","85299","85296","85234","85289","85212","85297","85082","85024","85074","85029","85022"
        ,"85027","85079","85050","85053","85068","85064","85061","85020","85025","85076","85072","85066","85083","85062","85054","85075"
        ,"85071","85032","85069","85023","85073","85063","85028","85021","85051","85067","85060","85080","85078","85290","85320","85337"
        ,"85306","85037","85304","85301","85035","85039","85380","85030","85363","85031","85303","85381","85307","85305","85033","85038"
        ,"85026","85351","85043","85335","85345","85339","85353","85036","85385","85302","85205","85216","85282","85203","85208","85215"
        ,"85201","85214","85206","85281","85274","85204","85211","85209","85275","85210","85202","85277","85207","85213","85327","85331"
        ,"85086","85087","85085","85377","85396","85340","85329","85343","85338","85323","85354","85355","85395","85309","85322","85326"
        ,"85392","85268","85250","85271","85261","85259","85255","85256","85267","85254","85070","85018","85269","85251","85258","85260"
        ,"85257","85253","85008","85266","85262","85264","85252","85263","85045","85001","85016","85007","85017","85040","85014","85042"
        ,"85006","85003","85019","85015","85010","85002","85046","85044","85041","85009","85012","85034","85048","85005","85011","85004"
        ,"85013","86443","86021","86404","86438","86433","86403","86437","86445","86405","86411","86406","86436","86409","86434","86413"
        ,"86402","86431","86444","86441","86412","86401","85360","86446","86426","86430","86439","86427","86429","86440","86442","86432"
        ,"85901","85933","86031","85929","85939","85935","86520","86047","85923","85934","86032","85902","85926","85912","85941","85942"
        ,"86029","85911","85937","85928","86025","86033","86034","86510","86043","86042","86054","86030","86039","85752","85706","85737"
        ,"85720","85719","85716","85745","85740","85714","85704","85754","85725","85731","85711","85732","85715","86704","85756","85702"
        ,"85728","85735","85722","85748","85746","85713","85705","85710","85741","85703","85750","85726","85730","85708","85701","85717"
        ,"85751","85743","85742","85734","85723","85733","85755","85749","85712","85747","85736","85718","85757","85629","85707","85622"
        ,"85614","85321","85652","85634","85653","85739","85658","85738","85641","85618","85219","85220","85623","85237","85218","85240"
        ,"85119","85243","85278","85118","85120","85143","85140","85217","85242","85142","85631","85130","85222","85294","85194","85230"
        ,"85293","85122","85238","85193","85223","85145","85132","85123","85231","85232","85139","85279","85128","85239","85138","85228"
        ,"85131","85648","85662","85637","85646","85645","85640","85624","85628","85621","85611","86334","85332","85324","86330","86332"
        ,"86343","86321","86357","86329","86303","86304","86323","86338","85362","86301","86315","86312","86305","86331","86302","86313"
        ,"86314","86327","86324","86333","86335","86342","86351","86340","86322","86336","86341","86325","86326","86320","85350","85364"
        ,"85366","85347","85367","85356","85333","85369","85365","85336","85349"
        ))
Col2 <- as.factor(
      c("APA-1","APA-1","APA-1","APA-1","APA-1","APA-1","APA-1","APA-1","APA-1","APA-1","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2"
        ,"APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","APA-2","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1"
        ,"CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1","CNC-1"
        ,"CNC-2","CNC-2","CNC-2","CNC-2","CNC-2","CNC-3","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1"
        ,"COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1","COH-1"
        ,"COH-1","GHM-1","GHM-1","GHM-1","GHM-1","GHM-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1"
        ,"GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GLA-1","GNL-1","GNL-1","LAP-1","LAP-1","LAP-1","LAP-1","LAP-1","LAP-1","LAP-1","LAP-1","LAP-2","MAR-1"
        ,"MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1"
        ,"MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-1","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10"
        ,"MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-10","MAR-11","MAR-11","MAR-11","MAR-11","MAR-11","MAR-11","MAR-11","MAR-11","MAR-11","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2"
        ,"MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2"
        ,"MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-2","MAR-20","MAR-20","MAR-20"
        ,"MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3"
        ,"MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-3","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4"
        ,"MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-4","MAR-5","MAR-5","MAR-5","MAR-5","MAR-5"
        ,"MAR-5","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6","MAR-6"
        ,"MAR-6","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7"
        ,"MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-7","MAR-8","MAR-8","MAR-8","MAR-8","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9"
        ,"MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MAR-9","MOH-1","MOH-1"
        ,"MOH-1","MOH-1","MOH-1","MOH-1","MOH-1","MOH-1","MOH-1","MOH-1","MOH-1","MOH-1","MOH-2","MOH-2","MOH-2","MOH-2","MOH-2","MOH-2","MOH-2"
        ,"MOH-2","MOH-2","MOH-2","MOH-3","MOH-3","MOH-3","MOH-3","MOH-3","MOH-3","MOH-3","MOH-3","MOH-4","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1"
        ,"NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-1","NVJ-2"
        ,"NVJ-2","NVJ-2","NVJ-2","NVJ-2","NVJ-2","NVJ-2","NVJ-2","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1"
        ,"PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1"
        ,"PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1"
        ,"PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-1","PIM-2","PIM-2","PIM-2","PIM-2","PIM-20","PIM-20","PIM-20","PIM-3","PIM-3","PIM-3","PIM-3","PIM-3"
        ,"PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1","PIN-1"
        ,"PIN-1","PIN-2","PIN-2","PIN-2","PIN-2","PIN-2","PIN-2","PIN-2","PIN-2","PIN-2","PIN-3","PIN-3","PIN-3","PIN-3","PIN-3","PIN-3","PIN-3"
        ,"PIN-3","PIN-3","PIN-3","PIN-3","PIN-3","PIN-3","SC-1","SC-1","SC-1","SC-1","SC-1","SC-1","SC-1","SC-1","SC-1","SC-1","YAV-1","YAV-1"
        ,"YAV-1","YAV-1","YAV-1","YAV-1","YAV-1","YAV-1","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2"
        ,"YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-2","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-3","YAV-4","YUM-1"
        ,"YUM-1","YUM-1","YUM-1","YUM-1","YUM-1","YUM-1","YUM-1","YUM-1","YUM-1","YUM-1"
        ))
Col3 <- c(
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,29,0,0,116,0,0,0,0,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,243,195,0,418,0,53,0,1,0,1,0,4,0,0,0
        ,0,1,0,2,10,0,0,4,0,17,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,59,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,81,3,0,11,1,0,150,28,0,0,0,0,172,0,135,243,50,70
        ,94,16,2,102,5,182,13,0,192,0,178,291,0,231,83,192,0,189,150,0,0,0,231,0,177,110,0,213,267,0,104,149,0,112,0,101,201,129,0,179,78,0,0,0,137
        ,0,0,0,0,65,0,30,0,0,268,0,111,0,0,113,64,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,81,121,101,52,43,0,0,0,21,25,71,83,14,33,86,0,23,99,84,121,156,160,90,0,0,89,155
        ,0,177,94,153,77,107,0,112,123,0,130,0,160,0,92,128,0,169,99,0,242,322,44,90,42,40,107,0,0,176,93,9,27,93,0,0,155,188,186,158,0,0,229,395,4
        ,0,323,0,156,0,189,292,359,122,113,68,121,116,1,0,8,47,0,109,23,39,47,84,106,29,16,42,64,0,0,0,189,170,22,23,5,205,0,0,10,81,0,0,306,0,0,313
        ,0,0,0,0,513,12,90,0,55,0,0,7,1,0,123,0,0,211,0,1,0,96,83,345,2,53,17,0,15,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,31,66,0,21
        ,18,48,0,5,44,0,0,0,41,0,33,0,28,0,0,9,0,38,53,35,29,77,44,0,68,0,68,0,2,0,0,68,69,0,0,0,30,30,25,52,3,58,21,45,0,9,61,0,0,0,14,25,27,0,35
        ,0,3,3,1,0,1,4,52,6,0,74,61,198,149,0,12,229,0,0,16,2,11,0,0,141,5,5,4,3,50,19,0,1,70,0,40,2,191,0,6,12,0,1,5,2,0,0,0,1,0,38,0,6,0,0,0,0,0
        ,2,133,0,99,3,2,189,82,0,125,2,0,0,228,90,45,14,45,5,211,0,96,273,0,92,284,0,82,765,0,0,303,13,0,0,617,1,37
      )
AZSubCounties<-data.frame(ZipCode = Col1, SubCounty = Col2, NumberToAggregate = Col3)

# Merge dataframes
MergedDF <- merge(AZSubCounties,AZOnlyDF,by.x="ZipCode",by.y="ZCTA5CE10",all.y=TRUE)
AZOnly@data <- MergedDF

#Plot original census zip codes
spplot(AZOnly,"NumberToAggregate",main = "Original census zip codes")

#Aggregate NumberToAggregate at the 'sub county' level
AZCoords <- coordinates(AZOnly)
AZIDs <- cut(AZCoords[,1], ????, include.lowest=TRUE)
AZOnlyDFAgg <- aggregate(MergedDF[,3], list(AZIDs), sum)

# This where I get stuck, I know that I'm supposed to union the polygons together somehow.  
# I've done research but I don't understand the 'cut' examples provided and how that works together with the IDs and polygons
AZUnion <- unionSpatialPolygons(AZOnly, AZIDs)

# Reconvert data frame to SpatialPolygons
NewAZ <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(AZUnion, AZOnlyDFAgg)

# Output geojson file (I'd like to output TopoJSON, but geojsonio doesn't have that functionality yet)
geojson_write(NewAZ,file="C:/Users/MyUsername/Documents/R/Data/NewAZ.geojson")
```

Comment: This might answer your question about missing zip codes: http://www.georeference.org/doc/zip_codes_are_not_areas.htm.  Every physical location within the territorial US does not necessarily have one, which is why there are "gaps" in the shapefile.

Comment: Does it matter that you have `NA` values in `MergedDF`? `sum(is.na(MergedDF))
[1] 46`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example aggregating zipcodes that fall within the state of Minnesota.   The source for the states geojson file is [here](https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces.geojson).

First, import states and zips:

```
require(sp)

zips <- readOGR("cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k.shp")
states <- readOGR("states.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")
```

then with `@proj4string` you will notice that the dataframes have differing CRS

Change the CRS of `states` to be identical to that of `zips` with:

```
states <- spTransform(states, CRS(proj4string(zips)))
```

Now we check and they are equal

```
> proj4string(states)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
> proj4string(zips)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Okay, now let's subset states by a random state - Minnesota:

```
MN <- states[states@data$name =='Minnesota', ]
plot(MN)
```

[image]

One great thing about R is that we can perform an intersect query between two spatial dataframes just as easily as we can subset a matrix.  For example, if we want to see which zipcodes intersect with `MN`, we subset `zips`:

```
zips_subset <- zips[MN,]

plot(zips_subset)
plot(MN, border="green", lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Now, if we want to dissolve all of the `zips_subset` polygons, it is simple:

```
> dissolved <-  gUnaryUnion(zips_subset)
> plot(dissolved)
```

[image]

Solution to subcounties:

**1.** Get rid of NA values in `AZOnly` because they do not contain a `$SubCounty` attribute:

```
> sum(is.na(AZOnly@data))
[1] 46
```

define a function to omit `NA`s in sp:

```
sp.na.omit <- function(x, margin=1) {
  if (!inherits(x, "SpatialPointsDataFrame") & !inherits(x, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")) 
    stop("MUST BE sp SpatialPointsDataFrame OR SpatialPolygonsDataFrame CLASS OBJECT") 
  na.index <- unique(as.data.frame(which(is.na(x@data),arr.ind=TRUE))[,margin])
  if(margin == 1) {  
    cat("DELETING ROWS: ", na.index, "\n") 
    return( x[-na.index,]  ) 
  }
  if(margin == 2) {  
    cat("DELETING COLUMNS: ", na.index, "\n") 
    return( x[,-na.index]  ) 
  }
}

> AZOnly <- sp.na.omit(AZOnly)

DELETING ROWS:  383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 

> sum(is.na(AZOnly@data))
[1] 0
```

**2.** Create a separate data.frame in which to aggregate `NumberToAggregate` by `SubCounty` and rename column to `sum`:

```
> index <- data.frame()
> index <- rbind(index, AZOnly@data)
> index <- aggregate(NumberToAggregate~SubCounty, sum, data=index)
colnames(index)[2] <- "sum"
```

**3.** Dissolve `AZOnly` by subcounties:

```
ScIDS <- AZOnly@data[["SubCounty"]]
AZ <- gUnaryUnion(AZOnly, id = ScIDS)
```

Now we are left with a Spatial Polygons object but we need a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame because we will need to merge with `index`

```
> class(AZ)
[1] "SpatialPolygons"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

**4.** Convert `AZ` to `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and merge by `SubCounty`:

The `row.names` are by SubCountry in `AZ` so they must be the same in `index`

```
head(row.names(AZ))
[1] "APA-1" "APA-2" "CNC-1" "CNC-2" "CNC-3" "COH-1"

row.names(index) <- index$SubCounty

head(row.names(index))
[1] "APA-1" "APA-2" "CNC-1" "CNC-2" "CNC-3" "COH-1"
```

**5.** Once `row.names` are equal in both dataframes we can merge and then plot:

```
output <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(AZ, index)


spplot(output, "sum", main ="sums")
```

[image]

Comment: I thank you for your help and I learned some useful new information with your example.  My challenge with the solution that you presented is that I'm not trying to do a spatial join.  I'm trying to create polygons that don't exist in any files by grouping already existing polygons together.  It is quite possible that what you have proposed will solve my problem but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: I will try to go by your example - you have forgotten to define `l`

Comment: Thanks.  The code should work until you hit this line "AZIDs <- cut(AZCoords[,1], ????, include.lowest=TRUE)"  because I'm not sure how to 'cut' coordinates or data frame the right way so that unionSpatialPolygons works correctly.

Comment: you could cut using `AZIDs <- cut(AZCoords[,1], unique(AZCoords[,1]), include.lowest=TRUE)`  if you want to have 405 breaks.  But I'm guessing you want something like 42 breaks because that is the amount of subcounties.  Essentially you want to dissolve by subcounty and then include the aggregate number of "zips" that went into that subcounty if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, I want to dissolve by subcounty and then include the aggregated NumberToAggregate for each subcounty.

Comment: BTW...I edited my earlier spplot command that had the errant 'l'.  Not sure where that came from, but it has been fixed.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a workaround - it's not the most efficient but works

Comment: is it the correct output?

Comment: Thank you.  Based on what you presented, it looks like that SHOULD work, however when I run this line:  'AZ <- gUnaryUnion(AZOnly, id = ScIDS)' I receive the following error:  'Error in slot(p, "Polygons") : cannot get a slot ("Polygons") from an object of type "NULL"'.  I can get everything up to that point to work.

Comment: I stared a new instance of R and I was able to get your solution to work!  Thanks!  Do you happen to have any good links that explain WHY this works?  I'm still not sure how R knows which lines to dissolve based only on the ID values of the polygons.